# Link to react как сделать его динамическим?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть такой код, принимаю в него параметры пропа, хочу организовать spa чтобы странички подтягивались, но хочу чтобы link был динамичным, как это сделать правильно?
react

```
         <ul>
     {Array.from(this.props.state).map((prop,index) =>{
        return(
           <li><Link to={prop.path}>{prop.title}</Link></li>
        )
     })}
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно `` <Link to={`/${prop.path}`}> `` убирая начальный слеш в зависимости от ситуации.
То есть если вы хотите перейти в `prop.path` от самого домена: `` <Link to={`/${prop.path}`}> ``, а если от какого-то путя то: `` <Link to={`/some/path/${prop.path}`}> `` или просто `` <Link to={`${prop.path}`}> `` и думаю надо убрать `return` из `map`